# Combining two queries to get total count and filtered list

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

I have a query that gets all user ids that has logged in within the past year.

Query1:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name
FROM logins
WHERE login_date BETWEEN "2015-09-01" AND "2016-09-01"
GROUP BY user_id;

Execution time: 625ms
```

And another query similar to above, now with additional filters to list the usernames with 'jeff'.

Query2:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name
FROM logins
WHERE login_date BETWEEN "2015-09-01" AND "2016-09-01"
AND user_name LIKE '%jeff%'
GROUP BY user_id;

Execution time: 587ms
```

Total execution time is 1212ms.

I use Query1 only to get the total number of logged in users within the year and Query2 to get the list of users with user_name like 'jeff'.

The problem is, I need to execute both queries and it takes longer.

Is there a way to combine both queries into just one and get the data I need i.e. the total count of logged in users and the list of logged in users with user_name like 'jeff'? at the same time minimizing the execution time?

---

Sample data:

```
user_id user_name   login_date
1   annie       2015-10-02
2   greg        2015-12-25
3   jeff        2015-11-05
4   aljeffar    2016-03-06
5   jeff1       2015-07-07
2   greg        2016-01-30
1   annie       2015-11-13
3   jeff        2016-02-14
2   greg        2016-09-30
3   jeff        2016-07-04
```

Query1 Result:

> ```
> user_id   user_name   
> 1 annie       
> 2 greg        
> 3 jeff        
> 4 aljeffar
> Total result count: 4 -- this should be the fix value of total_loggedin_users column below
> ```

Query2 Result:

> ```
>   user_id user_name
>   3   jeff    
>   4   aljeffar
> ```

Expected Final Result:

> ```
> user_id   user_name   total_loggedin_users
> 3 jeff        4
> 4 aljeffar    4
> ```

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. (The problem isn't clear to me.)

Comment: Show us the complete expected result, i.e. annie etc included!

Comment: that result should be the result of your second query. except that you also need to select the login_date. I'm confused by your question for getting the total count of jeffs and seeing your wished  result...

Comment: does every login by one user count for the total_loggedin_users or does the user only count once no matter how many logins this user had?

Comment: @Nebi total_loggedin_users should be the result count of the first query.

Comment: Did an answer help you? Then mark it as answer. So that the Question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       user_id, 
       count(*) as total, 
       sum(case when user_name LIKE '%jeff%' then 1 else 0 end) as jeff_count
FROM logins
WHERE login_date BETWEEN "2015-09-01" AND "2016-09-01"
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Run it just once and add a conditional sum to count jeffs.

Comment: the query is good but I need a list of jeffs not just the count.

Comment: This query only sums the amount when the user_id is the same not for all users with the user_name like '%jeff%'. Because you are grouping by user_id. So in order to get the amount of all jeffs you need to have an outer select with a sum of jeff_count.

Comment: The CASE WHEN worked for me without the SUM(). And in my system, I count the records returned by the query above and use array_filters to get the list of jeffs

Answer (score 1):

If you want your result only to show user_name like jeff and also have the overall count you might try this:

*Needed to do a Subselect to get the overall count in a column. Updated Query:*

```
SELECT  [USER_ID] ,
        [USER_NAME] ,
        CountAll
FROM    ( SELECT    [USER_ID] ,
                    [USER_NAME] ,
                    -- Window-Function (Only in SQL-Server) to get overall count
                    COUNT([USER_ID]) OVER ( ) AS CountAll
          FROM      dbo.logins
          WHERE     login_date BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2016-09-01'
          --Group so we don't count multiple logins of one user 
          GROUP BY  [USER_ID] ,
                    [USER_NAME]
        ) subselect
WHERE   [USER_NAME] LIKE '%jeff%'
```

Comment: updated query so that the overallcount is in the coloumn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Other variant.

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(user_name) AS list_of_jeffs, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(IF(user_name LIKE "%jeff%",1,0)) as jeff
FROM `pt_terminal` 
WHERE login_date BETWEEN "2015-09-01" AND "2016-09-01" 
GROUP BY user_id;
```